# Is '<?=' the same as 'echo'?

Tags: php, echo

I've found some page where people print strings on the web page with this:

```
<?= 'hello world'; ?>
```

Is this a faster way to `print` strings in one row of code or does it work different?

Comment: short tags are generally not recommend (http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

Comment: Yes it is, you can even omit the `;`. Generally however, you use this short form to print out the content variables, e.g. <?=$myVar?>, instead of direct strings (you can print those simply in HTML without any PHP)

Comment: Just to be correct: This is a short cut to "echo" and not to "print". Those are two different functions in PHP.

Comment: The intended use is as a templating tag. It is nice to be able to sprinkle an HTML document with <?=$title?>, <?=content?>... and quickly create a template with nothing but standard PHP

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. This would work as echo, but it IS NOT RECOMMENDED and many servers have got this availability disabled. It's called "short tag"

Comment: "Recommended" depends on your personal circumstances. If you control the server, or if short_open_tags are already enabled, using the short_open_tags is not a problem, and it can really help the readability of the code.

Comment: Yes, that's true. but <?  and  ?> is not used so often like before 3-6 years.

Comment: If you want your code to be portable to other servers (e.g. usable by anyone else), you better avoid things that can utterly break by a simple change in the ini.

Comment: but there are people which use server with unchangable  settings

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php), the `<?= ... ?>` form is a shortcut for `echo`, so they should be the same from a performance perspective.

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly the same as *just* `echo`, it's a shortcut syntax.

```
<?= 'hello world'; ?>
```

would be the same as:

```
<?php echo 'hello world'; ?>
```

The latter is recommended because `short_open_tags` might be disabled on your server.